# SystemOutOfMemory exception after working with Stream

Tags: c#, windows-phone, out-of-memory

That function rotates image stream on 90 degrees.
After I call it 5-6 times at Windows Phone I got `SystemOutOfMemory` exception

```
private WriteableBitmap _rotate(Stream stream)
{
    var bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource(stream);
    var src = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
    var w = src.PixelWidth;
    var h = src.PixelHeight;
    var p = src.Pixels;
    var dst = new WriteableBitmap(h, w);
    var i = 0;
    var rp = dst.Pixels;
    for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        for (var y = h - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            var srcInd = y * w + x;
            rp[i] = p[srcInd];
            i++;
        }
    }
    /* Trying to free memory, but nothing of that works */
    //bmp = null;
    //src = null;
    return dst;
}
```

I know that problem in that function, cause when I'm not calling - all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```